# Run a Docker container under a different service account when using Cloud Build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-build

I am using Cloud Build and would like to run a Docker container under a different service account than the standard Cloud Build service account (A).
The service account I would like to use (B) is from a different project.
One way to do it would be to put the json key on Cloud Storage and then mount it in the Docker container, but I think it should be possible with IAM policies too.
My cloubuild.yaml now contains the following steps:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v0.20.0'
    args:
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/namu-app:latest
      - --cache=true
      - --cache-ttl=168h
  - name: 'docker'
    args: ['run', '--network=cloudbuild', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/namu-app:latest']
```

The network is set so that Cloud Build service account is accessible to docker container - see https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#network.
So I think my container should have access to the Cloud Build service account.
Then I run the following code inside the Docker container:

```
import socket
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials, default

default_credentials, _ = default()
print("Token: {}".format(default_credentials.token))
play_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
    source_credentials=default_credentials,
    target_principal='google-play-api@api-0000000000000000-0000000.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    target_scopes=[],
    lifetime=3600)

TRACK = "internal"
PACKAGE_NAME = 'x.y.z'
APPBUNDLE_FILE = "./build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab"

socket.setdefaulttimeout(300)
service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3')
edits = service.edits()
edit_id = edits.insert(body={}, packageName=PACKAGE_NAME).execute()['id']
```

However, this fails with:

```
 googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/x.y.z/edits?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

I tried several ways of assigning service account roles, but no luck so far. I thought at first that explicitly 'impersonating' credentials might not be necessary (maybe it can be implicit?).
In summary, I want service account A from project P1 to run as service account B from project P2.
Any ideas?

Comment: The error you are getting is on the code side, try adding the required [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#playcustomapp): `target_scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']`.

Comment: Thank you. I added this, but the same error still occurs.

Comment: Are you getting the same result when running the code on you local environment?

Comment: No, from my local environment this exact same script works (just tested it). A difference is that the service account that I use locally is my own (user) service account, not the Cloud Build service account.

Comment: Did you also set permissions to the Cloud Build Service Account on the second project?

Comment: @JoseV I added the Cloud Build service account in the second project and gave it ‘run as service account’ permissions. (But it had no positive effect)

Answer (score 0):

You might follow to alternatives to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Give the Cloud Build service account the same permissions that has the service account you are using to run this on your local environment.
2. Authenticate with a different approach using a credentials file, as shown in [this code snippet](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v3/python/basic_list_apks_service_account.py):

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client


SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = (
    'ENTER_YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE@developer.gserviceaccount.com')


# Load the key in PKCS 12 format that you downloaded from the Google APIs
# Console when you created your Service account.
f = file('key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

# Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
# with the Credentials. Note that the first parameter, service_account_name,
# is the Email address created for the Service account. It must be the email
# address associated with the key that was created.
credentials = client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher')
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('androidpublisher', 'v3', http=http)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I gave the Cloud Build account project owner permissions, but still got the same error. The key that I am switching to is in a different project, so maybe something goes wrong when switching. I am pretty sure approach 2 will work, but using a credential file was exactly what I was trying to avoid. If it's the only way, I might have to use that approach in the end, however.

Comment: I ran some tests and I was able to manage resources of project P2 using a service account from project P1.
What I did was add the service account of P1 to P2 and assign it the roles "Service Account User" and "Project Owner". If no other permissions aside from "Service Account User" are assigned, I got a 403. Let me know if this is useful

Answer (score -1):

Using gcloud you can do `gcloud run services update SERVICE --service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`. Documentation also says that

> In order to deploy a service with a non-default service account, the
>   deployer must have the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission on the
>   service account being deployed.

See https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#gcloud for more details.

Comment: Thank you, but that page seems to be about ‘Cloud Run’. I am using ‘Cloud Build’.

Comment: The point is that the process should be the same. So I'm guessing the args in your yml need to include --service-account that points to the service account you want to use and you need to give the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission on that service account the the user you are authenticated as.

Comment: I am not sure there is such an option in the yml file. According to the docs Cloud Build uses a special service account, so it does not seem like I can run the whole build under a different service account (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account). If it is possible, I would like to know how.